# Can I make a bitwise copy of a C++ object?

Tags: c++

Can C++ objects be copied using bitwise copy? I mean using memcopy_s?  Is there a scenario in which that can go wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If they're Plain Old Data (POD) types, then this should work.  Any class that has instances of other classes inside it will potentially fail, since you're copying them without invoking their copy constructors.  The most likely way it will fail is one of their destructors will free some memory, but you've duplicated pointers that point to it, so you then try to use it from one of your copied objects and get a segfault.  In short, don't do it unless it's a POD and you're sure it will always be a POD.

Comment: Even POD is dangerous if an element is 'SomeType *x' and the space is allocated - you've now got two copies of one pointer, and it is likely that something will get double-deleted, which is not good.

Comment: Risky, yes, but it is not in itself an error. Since the type is POD, it doesn't have a sneaky destructor which will try to delete the pointer, so it only gets double-deleted if you do it yourself.

Answer (score 11):

No, doing so can cause a lot of problems.  You should always copy C++ types by using the assignment operator or copy constructor.

Using a bitwise copy breaks any kind of resource management because at the end of the day you are left with 2 objects for which 1 constructor has run and 2 destructors will run.

Consider as an example a ref counted pointer.

```
void foo() {
  RefPointer<int> p1(new int());
  RefPointer<int> p2;
  memcpy(&p2,p1,sizeof(RefPointer<int>));
}
```

Now both p1 and p2 are holding onto the same data yet the internal ref counting mechanism has not been notified.  Both destructors will run thinking they are the sole owner of the data potentially causing the value to be destructed twice.

Comment: It's worth noting that even with POD'ish classes (i.e. POD fields only, but, say, also virtual method), it's still technically U.B., even when it works.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the C++ object you are trying to copy. In general the owner of the C++ object's memory is the object itself, so trying to "move" or "copy" it with something like memcopy_s is going behind its back which is going to get you in trouble more often than not.

Usually if a C++ object is intended to be copied or moved, there are APIs within the class itself that facilitate this.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single object, why not use assignment operator (I suppose the compiler-generated assignment operator could be implemented in terms of `memcpy` if that is so advantageous, and the compiler knows better whether your class is a POD.)

If you want to copy an array of objects, you can use std::copy. Depending on the implementation, this may end up using `memmove` (one more thing that you can mess up - the buffers may overlap; I don't know whether the nonstandard `memcpy_s` somehow checks for that) if the involved types allow that. Again, the decision is done by the compiler, which will get it right even if the types are modified.

Answer (score 0):

In general if your structure contains pointers, you can't memcpy it because the structure would most likely allocate new memory spaces and point to those. A memcpy can't handle that.

If however your class only has primitive, non-pointer types, you *should* be able to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem of unbalanced resource management calls in the two instance you end up with after a memcopy (as @JaredPar and @rmeador pointed), if the object supports a notion of an instance ID doing a memcopy will leave you with two instances with the same ID. This can lead to all sorts of "interesting" problems to hunt later on, especially if your objects are mapped to a database.