# Copying objects with only move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Before anything else, let me take you all into the highway of my thoughts (to say it simply, *I'm just imagining these things*)

Suppose, I am using a third-party library class that uses move semantics (r-value references). Here is its definition:

```
class VeryHeavyObject {
    VeryHeavyObject(const VeryHeavyObject& obj); // copy constructor
    VeryHeavyObject& operator= (const VeryHeavyObject& obj); // copy operator

public:
    VeryHeavyObject(); // constructor

    VeryHeavyObject(VeryHeavyObject&& obj); // move constructor
    VeryHeavyObject& operator= (VeryHeavyObject&& obj); // move operator

    // ....
};
```

Apparently, the author's really concerned about the cost of copying of `VeryHeavyObject` and decided to force everything to be moved (More apparently, he doesn't know how to design classes with move semantics). But then, in some point of my code, I need to have a **copy** of `VeryHeavyObject`.

Well, the core question is:
***How can I copy an object with only a move constructor and a move operator?***

P.S.: I have tried but I can't really contact the author of the library (I think he's on vacation).

Comment: Is there a complete interface of VeryHeavyObject? There may be a `.clone()` method.

Comment: @KennyTM Maybe the author's just don't know how to design the class and forgot a clone method. (Please do get my point)

Comment: Is it because the object is heavy, or because it should really not be copied (e.g. it represents a unique resource)?

Comment: Why do you need to copy it in the first place? May be it's not necessary. e.g. use `emplace_back` instead of  `push_back` for stl containers...

Comment: I don't get it... can't you just change the header file and put in some inline copy constructors/assignments?

Comment: Guys! Please! Do try to get my point. I'm after on the specific hows and the the overall design of the (imaginary) software.

Comment: Note: in C++11 you should use `= delete` to remove methods, rather than just making them `private` (which provoke a link error if they are still used). But then it is moot because §12.8/7 precises *If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted;*, so you're doing extra work which hampers the compiler's diagnostics ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM. So it means you have to *explicitly* define the copy constructor. Right?

Comment: @MarkGarcia: Depends on the objective. If you provide a move constructor or move assignment operator AND you still want a copy constructor, then yes you have to explicitly define your copy constructor. On the other hand, note that `Type(Type const&) = default;` count as explicit definition :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You cannot.**

However, provided that you have sufficient access to its internals (getters and the like), then you can construct a *clone* by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A well defined interface, and we will assume that this is the case, some methods may not be available because the author wants to discourage certain uses for performance reasons. A well-known example is `std::list`, which does not include a `[]` operator because it has `O(n)` complexity compared with `O(1)` in other containers, such as `std::vector`.

In this case, the author of the library wants to discourage the use of copies because, as you state in your question, it is very costly. But this does not mean that it is impossible. If you really need to do it, you can probably write your own `Clone()` function that takes data from the original `VeryHeavyObject` as appropriate, constructs a new one with these data and returns it using `std::move`.  Since we haven't got the interface for `VeryHeavyObject` we cannot try to do it, but I'm sure you can.

Comment: I want to do it *without* modifying the class's interface.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: you misread, Gorpik never mentionned modifying the class interface.

Comment: @MarkGarcia Matthieu is right, I'm not asking you to modify the class interface, but to add a free function to do the cloning. Which is more or less what he himself suggested in his accepted answer, so that's fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be possible.

The class has *declared* the copies private, but we can't see whether the functions are ever *defined*. You seem to assume that the class has a copy operation that it's hiding away from you to stop you doing something slow, but that might not be the case. Some objects simply cannot be copied. For examples, consider streams.

You wouldn't expect privately-declared-but-not-defined functions in C++11, but there's no law against it. Anyway even if there is an implemented private copy function, it's probably private for a reason (maybe it can only be used under certain controlled circumstances: the class internals know how to use it safely and you don't). So if there's no public copy, then as far as this class's API is concerned it cannot be copied.

Perhaps the class has enough public accessors, that you can interrogate it for the state you need, and construct a new object that matches it. If so then you could reasonably complain to the author of the class that it *should* be publicly copyable. If not then maybe it has state that can't be duplicated.

Anything that provides *unique* access to something (streams, drivers, locks) has a reason not to be copyable, because the original and the copy can't both provide unique access to the same thing. Admittedly `dup` means that even file descriptors don't physically provide unique access to something, let alone the streams that wrap them. But a stream has state involving buffered data not yet written, which means that copying them would introduce complexity that the class is designed to protect you from. So logically you normally use a stream as though it is the only way to access something.

If the copy assignment operator is implemented, then you might be able to hack [a way to call it even though it's private](http://bloglitb.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html). That won't work for the copy constructor, though, you can't take pointers to constructors. As a brutal hack you *could* `#define private public` before including its header: it's undefined behavior but it might work on the implementation you're using. Forking the third-party source would be better.

Comment: So there's no (at least portable) way to copy such objects.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: there's no general way to copy any such object, no. You have to look at the particular class, work out why it isn't publicly copyable, and then decide whether you or the author can do anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not possible without modifying the class, because there might be private data that you cannot access. It might be possible if a shallow copy is sufficient, because then you [should be able to do it with a `memccpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021333/can-i-use-memcpy-in-c-to-copy-classes-that-have-no-pointers-or-virtual-functio). (Note that if the class does not have any virtual members or pointers, shallow and deep copy are the same).

Comment: I consider it extremely unlikely that an object which can be moved efficiently can be copied bitwise without wreaking havoc on the copy once the original has been destroyed.